# C# custom cryptography function

Tags: c#, string, cryptography

I'm trying think of ideas for hiding a string. So far I have a function that converts each character in a string to its decimal value. Then it takes those values and adds one to hide and subtracts 1 to show the string.. Then after it's hidden or shown, it is converted back into ASCII characters.

So this string "Hello" would become "72 101 108 108 111" then if you add 1 "73 102 109 109 112" and that would become "Ifmmp". To decode that you just subtract 1.

As you can tell this isn't very secure...

I need ideas for this type of string hiding.

Comment: you are right, what you describe is rather insecure - what is your goal exactly ?

Comment: Cryptographic security and recognizable patterns are mutually exclusive. What you are trying to do will not be secure regardless of implementation.

Comment: No, I was just asking for ideas of manipulating a string to make it unreadable.

Comment: @Tr0y so it is not for learning purposes ? then just use your fantasy...

Comment: I asked the question in order to get other peoples ideas.

Comment: @Tr0y If you don't want **us** to tell you what to do then **what are you doing here?**

Comment: @Tr0y then read up on steganography + cryptogrpahy... this should give you plenty of ideas... do you need links to resources which describe ?

Comment: @Tr0y then just implement any of the available algorithms (DES , Triple DES, AES, etc..) the one you described (Caesar) exists already (since ages !) and is one of the simplest forms of substitution (read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher)).

Comment: For simple text hiding, read about Rot13.

Answer (score 6):

*Don't* try to invent your own cryptographic systems if you want any real security.

Use one of the algorithms provided by the framework in [`System.Security.Cryptography`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

The system you proposed is not even something new. It's called a [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) with a shift of 1. There are well known methods for cracking Caesar ciphers even if you don't know the shift.

Comment: @Tr0y Why is that not what you want? There are *extremely* few reasons to invent your own cryptographic algorithm for anything other than tinkering.